# Levinson's theorem in non-commutative quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, non-commutative-theory

[Levinson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levinson%27s_theorem) is a fundamental result from the scattering theory of spherically symmetric potentials in ordinary quantum mechanics. It relates the number of bound states $n$ for a given potential to the scattering phase shift $\delta(k)$ at zero incident momentum.

The statement of the theorem is that $\delta(0) - \delta(\infty) = n\pi$ (with some subtleties related to s-wave scattering that I have glossed over), where the convention is to assume that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \delta(k) = 0$, i.e. that a particle with sufficient momentum will not have its phase affected by a potential.

Non-commutative Quantum Mechanics (NCQM) is an extension to ordinary quantum mechanics where the components of the position operator no longer commute amongst themselves. For example in two spatial dimensions this could be written as $[\hat{x}_i, \hat{x}_j] = i\theta$, with i and j taking the values 1 or 2, and $\theta$ a real quantity specifying the amount of non-commutativity.

Is it known whether Levinson's theorem, or some modified version of it, holds for the scattering of particles in NCQM? It would be interesting if NCQM led to a modification of the theorem, as this would be an obvious signature to search for in experiments.

Since we would presumably only be able to probe any expected spatial non-commutativity at high momenta, the form of Levinson's theorem in ordinary QM does not seem very useful, unless the expectation that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \delta(k) = 0$ is modified, or some completely new effect becomes relevant.

I know how to prove Levinson's theorem in the ordinary case by evaluating a function related to the [Jost function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jost_function) along a specific contour in the complex plane, but I cannot do the same for the NCQM case because I do not know how the Jost function is altered in that case.